# Python - strange Output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have `list_IP` a list that contains some IP's

When I print 1st element it gives `23.20.0.0` but when i try to find the same element it says false.

How is that possible?

//Code

```
print list_IP[0]
IP = "23.20.0.0"
print IP in list_IP
```

//Output

```
23.20.0.0
False
```

Comment: `"23.20.0.0" in ["23.20.0.0"]` is `True`, so please update with a [mcve]. Are you sure the items in the list are actually strings, not other objects with a custom `__str__` or `__repr__`? What does `repr(list_IP[0])` show?

Comment: Trailing whitespace?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: okay, let me check it will take 3-4 mins, it's a bigger module for complete run

Comment: Then you definitely need to be cutting it down to an MCVE, otherwise it will take forever for you to debug.

Comment: you can also print type(list_IP[0]). It might not be in string type.

Comment: it gives <class 'netaddr.ip.IPAddress'>

Comment: Then that's the problem! the type is not string, so even though it prints like  "23.20.0.0" it is actually something more than that!

Comment: So encoding string "23.20.0.0" to this type <class 'netaddr.ip.IPAddress'> should work?

Comment: Or converting the instance to a string.

Comment: @Daniel but for that I will have to convert type of whole list which is a costly operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need the string value of IPs you can convert the values in the list to String. Like:

```
str_ips = [str(ip) for ip in list_IP]
```

If you need the real values, you can check only the string values manually in a for loop. Like:

```
def is_in(ip_list, str_ip):
    for ip in ip_list:
        if str(ip) == str_ip:
            return True
    return False
```